# How to implement native browser based OpenID Connect authentication in Python?

Tags: python, openid-connect, desktop-application

I am writing a console application in Python, which has to communicate with a network service using OpenID Connect based authentication.

The users of the tool usually already are logged in using their favorite browser.

How can I open/ call the native browser from Python in a way, that I can return the access token?

Opening a http server, which gets a request via redirect URI does not work due to the configured personal firewall for most of the users by IT.

The `webbrowser.open` seems to provide no way to return data.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/web-authentication-broker seems to be no working solution for my kind of application, due to not being a Windows application registered in the Microsoft Store, but an in-house tool.

You may assume that all users use recent Windows clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A console app uses desktop OAuth according to [RFC8252](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252#section-7.1) and these are the login return options from a browser:

- Loopback
- Private URI scheme

The latter may work for your use case, where the redirect URI has this form. The scheme is registered for the current user and this does not require admin privileges:

x-mycompany-myapp:/callback

You can run my [Desktop Code Sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.desktopsample.final) to see how this looks. You can test whether this works for users via a [web page like this](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.desktopsample.final/blob/master/web/postlogin.html).

I'm no expert on Python but there are [Python online tutorials available on this topic](https://dev.to/pybash/making-a-custom-protocol-handler-and-uri-scheme-part-2-4b51).